# I am trying to add an image to HTML using javascript but there is no content?

Tags: javascript, html

When I try to add the Image with javascript, it displays the boarder of the image but there is no content inside. It is just an empty blank box. Any ideas?

Javascript:

```
var img=document.createElement("img");
img.src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500";
var src = document.getElementById("gameboard");
src.appendChild(img);
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <img id="gameboard">
  </div>
</body>
```

Jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/bj5d6t7k/1/

Comment: You should append the newly-created image into the div, not into img.

Comment: You are appending an `img` child to an `img` parent. This is not allowed. Just set `img.src`, no need to make a new element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to append image inside another image which is not allowed. Simply set the *src* attribute of the existing image:

```js
var img=document.getElementById("gameboard");
img.src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500";
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <img id="gameboard">
  </div>
</body>
```

**OR:** If you want to create the element and append that with [Node.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

> The [Node.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) method adds a node to the ***end of the list of children*** of a specified parent node.

```js
var img=document.createElement("img");
img.src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500";
var gamecontiner = document.getElementById("gamecontiner");
gamecontiner.appendChild(img);
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="gamecontiner">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: what if i want to add the image to a specific div? say, my div id="gameconatiner"... Does the append now become useful? or do I just dictate where the image goes in the HTML? thanks

Comment: @JillJohn, simply target the div element `var src = document.getElementById("gameconatiner");`.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this below code

```
var img = new Image();
var div = document.getElementById('gameboard');

img.onload = function() {
div.appendChild(img);
};

img.src = 'path/to/image.jpg'
```

As per your code you are appending one image above another one

Answer (score 1):

After load document then access node. 
Give id to div tag.
See below,

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500";
        var srcimg = document.getElementById("gameboard");
        srcimg.appendChild(img);
     });
</script>

<body>
    <div id="gameboard">
    </div>
</body>
```